# Python Tokenization

Tags: python, tokenize

I am new with Python and I have a Tokenization assignment 
The Input is a .txt file with sentences
and output is .txt file with Tokens, and When I say Token i mean: simple word, ',' , '!' , '?' , '.' ' " '

I have this function: 
Input: 
Elemnt is a word with or without Punctuation, could be word like: Hi or said: or said"
StrForCheck : is an array of Punctuation that i want to separate from the words
TokenFile: is my output file

def CheckIfSEmanExist(Elemnt,StrForCheck, TokenFile):

```
FirstOrLastIsSeman = 0

for seman in StrForCheck:
    WordSplitOnSeman = Elemnt.split(seman)
    if len(WordSplitOnSeman) > 1:
        if Elemnt[len(Elemnt)-1] == seman:
            FirstOrLastIsSeman = len(Elemnt)-1
        elif Elemnt[0] == seman:
            FirstOrLastIsSeman = 1

if FirstOrLastIsSeman == 1:
    TokenFile.write(Elemnt[0])
    TokenFile.write('\n')
    TokenFile.write(Elemnt[1:-1])
    TokenFile.write('\n')

elif FirstOrLastIsSeman == len(Elemnt)-1:
    TokenFile.write(Elemnt[0:-1])
    TokenFile.write('\n')
    TokenFile.write(Elemnt[len(Elemnt)-1])
    TokenFile.write('\n')

elif FirstOrLastIsSeman == 0:
    TokenFile.write(Elemnt)
    TokenFile.write('\n')
```

The Code loops over the Punctuation Array, and if he finds one, i check if the Punctuation was the first letter or the last letter in the word, and write in my output file the word and the Punctuation each in a different line

But My Problem is that it works wonderful on the whole text except those words: 
Jobs" , created" , public" , police"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that

```
for l in open('some_file.txt', 'r'):
    ...
```

iterates over each line, so you just need to consider what to do within a line.

Consider the following function:

```
def tokenizer(l):
    prev_i = 0
    for (i, c) in enumerate(l):
        if c in ',.?!- ':
            if prev_i != i:
                yield l[prev_i: i]
            yield c
            prev_i = i + 1
    if prev_i != 0:
        yield l[prev_i: ]
```

It "spits out" tokens as it goes along. You can use it like this:

```
l = "hello, hello, what's all this shouting? We'll have no trouble here"
for tok in tokenizer(l):
    print tok
```

---

```
hello
,

hello
,

what's

all

this

shouting
?

We'll

have

no

trouble

here
```

Comment: but i also need to write the punctuation in my file 
meaning, according to your sentence my output should be:
helo  ,  hello  ,  what's  al l this  shouting  ?